# RecyclerView image jumps when scrollup?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

I am designing a facebook type app where images are of different sizes. I am using height to wrap_content of the imageView and Glide for image loading from firebase.
When I scroll from top to bottom the adapter loads the image. it is working fine. But when I scroll from bottom to top recyclerView need to show the previous images. But the scrolling is not smooth(scrolling from bottom to top). It jumps because the image suddenly loaded to the imageView from GLide cache. As the height of the imageView is wrap_content so the imageView becomes suddenly large. So effect as jumping appears. I don't want to fix the height of the imageView as it does not give good user experience(white space comes if the image is too large). Also, I don't want center_crop, because it does not show the full image. I have searched over the internet but could not any solution that works fine. Please help.

ImageView code

```
   <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/single_post_image_view_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:minHeight="350dp"
            android:maxHeight="800dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            />
```

Glide code

```
Glide.with(context).load(postsModel.getThumbImageUrl())
                 .apply(new RequestOptions().override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
                .into(postsViewHolder.postImage);
```

Comment: Whats the value of `Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL`?

Comment: Show us what is in onBindViewHolder method! And show us what methods are you using for RecyclerView

Comment: Any solution here? Got the same issue but with coil.